# 3D Bar graph using OpenGLES in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, bar-chart

I am creating a bar graph in android using opengl

from an activity I'm calling the renderer and from the renderer I'm  calling a cube(im using cubes for showing the bars)

Here is my renderer code:

```
public class BarRenderer implements Renderer {

int[] vals;
private float translatex, translatez, scaly;

public BarRenderer(boolean useTranslucentBackground, int[] vals) {
    mTranslucentBackground = useTranslucentBackground;
    this.vals = vals;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.vals.length; i++) {
        mcube[i] = new Cube();
    }
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    translatex = 0.5f;
    scaly = 0.8f;
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        gl.glTranslatef((-1.0f + (translatex * i)), 0.0f, translatez);
        gl.glRotatef(mAngle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glScalef(0.4f, scaly * vals[i], 0.6f);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        mcube[i].draw(gl);
    }
    mTransY = .075f;
    mAngle = -60.0f;
    translatez = -7.0f;
    Log.i("Draw", "called");
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float aspectRatio;
    float zNear = .1f;
    float zFar = 1000;
    float fieldOfView = 80.0f / 57.3f;
    float size;
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_NORMALIZE);
    aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    size = zNear * (float) (Math.tan((double) (fieldOfView / 2.0f)));
    gl.glFrustumf(-size, size, -size / aspectRatio, size / aspectRatio,
            zNear, zFar);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
    if (mTranslucentBackground) {
        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

private boolean mTranslucentBackground;
private Cube[] mcube = new Cube[4];
private float mTransY;
private float mAngle;

}
```

but unfortunately it is giving the bar graph like this:

[image]

anyone will understand this is not exactly like a bar graph
but please point out my faults here, where am i doing wrong:

1>the bar heights are 4 1 2 1 but they r not accurately of their sizes

2>the space between the bars are supposed to be .5f apart but they start with a big gap but reduce repeatedly after every bar

3>how to start them from one base plane

EDIT:

4> can I animate the growth of this bars?how to do that

My cube code:

```
public class Cube {
private ByteBuffer mTfan1;
private ByteBuffer mTfan2;
private int bar;

public Cube(int i) {
    
    this.bar = i;
    
    float vertices[] = { 
            
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,

            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f 
    };

    byte maxColor = (byte) 255;
    byte colors[][] =
    {   
            {maxColor,maxColor, 0,maxColor},
            {0, maxColor,maxColor,maxColor},
            {0, 0, 0,maxColor},
            {maxColor, 0,maxColor,maxColor},
            {maxColor, 0, 0,maxColor},
            {0, maxColor, 0,maxColor},
            {0, 0,maxColor,maxColor},
            {0, 0, 0,maxColor} 
    };

    byte tfan1[] =
    {
            1,0,3,
            1,3,2,
            1,2,6,
            1,6,5,
            1,5,4,
            1,4,0
    };
    byte tfan2[] =
    {
                7,4,5,
                7,5,6,
                7,6,2,
                7,2,3,
                7,3,0,
                7,0,4
    };
        
    byte indices[] =
    { 0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 3 };

    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    
    mFVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    mFVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    mFVertexBuffer.position(0);
    
    mColorBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length);
    mColorBuffer.put(colors[bar]);
    mColorBuffer.position(0);
    
    mTfan1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tfan1.length);
    mTfan1.put(tfan1);
    mTfan1.position(0);
    
    mTfan2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tfan2.length);
    mTfan2.put(tfan2);
    mTfan2.position(0);
}

public void draw(GL10 gl)
{
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, mFVertexBuffer);
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, mColorBuffer);
    gl.glDrawElements( gl.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 6 * 3, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mTfan1);
    gl.glDrawElements( gl.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 6 * 3, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mTfan2);
}

private FloatBuffer mFVertexBuffer;
private ByteBuffer mColorBuffer;
private ByteBuffer mIndexBuffer;
}
```

i think something has to be done in the draw method but what??how to animate here?

please help
thanks

Answer (score 2):

2  Before glTranslate and rotate calls you should use glPushMatrix and after that glPopMatrix functions, or call glTranslate without increment. Because glTranslate multiply existing projection matrix on new matrix from glTranslate parameters

3

```
gl.glPushMatrix() ;
gl.glTranslate(0,y,0);
mcube[i].draw(gl);
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

with y= - Barheight/2 in your case or change vertex coordinates of your bars

Comment: thanks a lot
and can you tell me how to make them stand on a single plane??

they are still standing at uneven heights

one is standing at a certain height the next one is at a bit higher ground

Comment: that happens because low vertex has y=-2.0f. You have to change low y coordinates of cube to 0 or call glTranslate(0, 2.0f,0) before cube.draw(). for other bars 2.0f should be changed to their low y values

Comment: right now all my scaling values are ranging between 1-4 so i have made it like this

        gl.glTranslatef((-3.0f + (translatex * i)), -5+(scaly * vals[i]), translatez);

its working for now but i think their will be a better procedure for this

Comment: can you help me out with piechart too??
I have managed to draw a circle any colour i can rotate it, translate it but i can't make it a cylinder and how to draw the pie chart actually in the circle
please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I have done creating the 3d bar graph though I have some other issues right now
but I believe some one might be helpful with this code.

Myrenderer class:

```
public class BarRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

int[] vals;
private float translatex, scaly;
// For controlling cube's z-position, x and y angles and speeds (NEW)
float angleX = 0; // (NEW)
float angleY = 0; // (NEW)
float speedX = 0; // (NEW)
float speedY = 0; // (NEW)
float translatez;

public BarRenderer(Context context, boolean useTranslucentBackground,
        int[] vals) {
    mTranslucentBackground = useTranslucentBackground;
    mfloor = new Cube(0);
    mwall = new Cube(0);

    this.vals = vals;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.vals.length; i++) {
        mcube[i] = new Cube(i);
    }
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    translatex = 2.0f;
    scaly = 0.8f;
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        mTransY = -5 + (scaly * vals[i]);
        gl.glTranslatef((-3.0f + (translatex * i)), mTransY, translatez);
        gl.glRotatef(mAngleX, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glRotatef(mAngleY, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glScalef(0.4f, scaly * vals[i], 0.4f);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        mcube[i].draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
     mTransY = .075f;
//      mAngleX = -90.0f;
//      mAngleY = -0.01f;
    mAngleX += speedX;
    mAngleY += speedY;
    translatez = -6.0f;
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float aspectRatio;
    float zNear = .1f;
    float zFar = 1000;
    float fieldOfView = 80.0f / 57.3f;
    float size;
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_NORMALIZE);
    aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    size = zNear * (float) (Math.tan((double) (fieldOfView / 2.0f)));
    gl.glFrustumf(-size, size, -size / aspectRatio, size / aspectRatio,
            zNear, zFar);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
    if (mTranslucentBackground) {
        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

private boolean mTranslucentBackground;
private Cube[] mcube = new Cube[4];
private Cube mfloor, mwall;
private float mTransY;
private float mAngleX,mAngleY;

}
```

and myGLsurfaceview class:

```
public class MyBarGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

BarRenderer renderer; // Custom GL Renderer

// For touch event
private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320.0f;
private float previousX;
private float previousY;

public MyBarGLSurfaceView(Context context,
        boolean useTranslucentBackground, int[] vals) {
    super(context);
    renderer = new BarRenderer(context, useTranslucentBackground, vals);
    this.setRenderer(renderer);
    // Request focus, otherwise key/button won't react
    this.requestFocus();
    this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}

// Handler for key event
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent evt) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT: // Decrease Y-rotational speed
        renderer.speedY -= 01.1f;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT: // Increase Y-rotational speed
        renderer.speedY += 01.1f;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP: // Decrease X-rotational speed
        renderer.speedX -= 01.1f;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN: // Increase X-rotational speed
        renderer.speedX += 01.1f;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A: // Zoom out (decrease z)
        renderer.translatez -= 0.2f;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z: // Zoom in (increase z)
        renderer.translatez += 0.2f;
        break;
    }
    return true; // Event handled
}

// Handler for touch event
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent evt) {
    float currentX = evt.getX();
    float currentY = evt.getY();
    float deltaX, deltaY;
    switch (evt.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        // Modify rotational angles according to movement
        deltaX = currentX - previousX;
        deltaY = currentY - previousY;
        renderer.angleX += deltaY * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR;
        renderer.angleY += deltaX * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR;
    }
    // Save current x, y
    previousX = currentX;
    previousY = currentY;
    return true; // Event handled
}
}
```

though it is done still I would like if anyone can please answer me

1> how to make this bar graphs to grow animatedly, right now when this bar graph activity starts the bar graph appears but i want the bar graph to grow animatedly not just show it

2> how to create a base and a background wall to the bar graph like this link http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#column-and-bar

3> and I was trying to rotate or move the bar graph as per user touch movements i tried the code like another example, you will see that code too and that is why i created this glsurfaceview class of my own, but for some reason it is not working, don't know where and what i have missed, if anyone have any idea please point it out to me

thanks